# Stack and Block of Memory Which one is best?

Tags: stack

from Stack (can access data in a specific order) and Block of Memory (can access data randomly), which one is best?
and why?

Comment: That's a very broad question. It can't be answered well within the scope of this page. Every memory model has its pros and cons in terms of different use cases. I suggest you narrow it down for a special use.

Comment: in the sense of Operating System which one is best?
and why?

Comment: Still too broad. Stack e.g. is useful for handling interrupts or calls, block for tabular data (task context). It's like asking: Is cab or airplane better for travelling.

Answer (score 0):

That's like asking which tool is better: a screwdriver or a hammer. Neither is better than the other in general. Each is used for specific jobs.

You use a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) whenever you need last-in, first-out behavior. You use a block of memory when you need random access.

Operating systems use lots of different data structures, including random access memory blocks, stacks, queues, etc.

If you want to know when to use which, then I suggest you do a little research on your own.